# In JavaScript/Node.js, how to use Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

In JavaScript/Node.js, how to use Async/Await for the below code to return placeName with a,b,c & d.

test.csv is having c,d

```
var placeName = ["a","b"];
var csvFile = 'test.csv';
fs.readFile(csvFile, 'UTF-8', function(err, csv) {
  $.csv.toArrays(csv, {}, function(err, data) {
    for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
      console.log(data[i]); //Will print every csv line as a newline
      placeName.push(data[i][0].toString());
    }
  });
   console.log(placeName); //Inside the function the array show a,b,c,d
});

// Prints only a and b. Did not add c & d from the csv.
console.log(placeName);
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  When you post here, we expect that you've first done some basic research on your question and then you post here when you are educated on the concept, but got stuck somewhere specific in your implementation.  We aren't a coding service that just writes code from scratch for you.  There are hundreds of general tutorials on the web on how to use async/await.  Your code shows no awareness of any of those tutorials at all.  Please read first, then attempt an implementation using what you've read and post back when you get stuck.

Comment: I'll give you a hint to start with.  `await` only works with functions that return a promise so first you have to make any asynchronous operations you use work via promises, not via plain callbacks and then you can use `await` on the functions that return promises.

Comment: You will have to first understand what Promises are since the new `async/await` syntax is really syntactic sugar over them.

Comment: Start with understanding synchronous vs asynchronous code. Calling `fs.readFile` in the same call out from the event loop as you log 'placeName' is an example of synchronous code. Without waiting for asynchronous call backs from the read operation to take place,you only see the value of `placeName` it was initialized to. Update occurs asynchronously, some time later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Create a function returning a promise

The `await` operator waits for a promise to be fulfilled and can only be used within `async` functions - which return a promise when called. So updating place names will need to be written as a function that returns a promise. Using a single promise for all operations is possible but not recommended:

```
function addNames(placeName, csvFile) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(csvFile, 'UTF-8', function(err, csv) {
            if(err) {
               reject(err);
            }
            else {
                $.csv.toArrays(csv, {}, function(err, data) {
                    if( err) {
                        reject( err);
                    }
                    else {
                        for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
                            console.log(data[i]); //print supplied data elements
                            placeName.push(data[i][0].toString());
                        }
                    }
                    resolve( placeName);
                });

            }
        });
    });
}
```

Although untested, this is based on the posted code: the input `placeName` array is modified in place. If fulfilled, the promise value is set to the modified array. However ....

#### Reducing indented code

Notice the code becomes more indented the more node style callback operations are added? Taken to extreme this can result in a condition known as "call back hell" - difficult to write, compile without error or maintain.

Removing nested callbacks is one of the design aims of promises and can be achieved by promisifying operations separately. The following example separates not just reading and decoding, but transforming the decoded data and adding it to an existing array:

```
function readCsvFile( csvFile) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject)  => {
        fs.readFile(csvFile, 'UTF-8',
           (err, csv) => err ? reject(err) : resolve( csv)
        );
    });
}
function decodeCsv( csv) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        $.csv.toArrays(csv, {},
           (err, data) => err ? reject( err) : resolve( data)
        );
    });
}
function extractNames( data) {
   return data.map( item => item[0].toString());
}

function addNames( placeName, csvFile) {
    return readCsvFile( csvFile)
    .then(decodeCsv)
    .then(extractNames)
    .then(  // push new names to placeName and return placeName
       names => names.reduce( (a,name) => {a.push(name);return a}, placeName)
     );
}
```

### Calling as part of a promise chain

Usage without using async/await requires adding promise handlers for fulfillment and rejection to be called asynchronously after data becomes available or an error occurs:

```
var placeName = ["a","b"];
var csvFile = 'test.csv';

addNames( placeName, csvFile)
.then( placeName => console.log(placeName)) // log updated places
.catch( err => console.log( err));  // or log the error.
```

### Usage of `await`

As mentioned, the `await` operator can only be used inside async functions. It waits for fulfilled promise data so that it can be processed further inside the same function.

```
async function example() {

    var placeName = ["a","b"];
    var csvFile = 'test.csv';

    await addNames( placeName, csvFile);
    // do something with placeName

    return somethingElse;       
}
```

Adding fulfillment and rejection handlers to the promise returned by calling `example` has not been shown.

### About `return await` ...

Note that a promise returned from an async function resolves the promise returned by  calling the function. Hence the coding pattern of

```
 return await operand
```

contains an unnecessary `await` operator.

### Writing async functions instead of ordinary ones (TLDR)

Using `async` functions in node still requires converting operations which use  error/success callbacks into requests that returns a promise ("promisifying" the operation), but syntactically allows writing code processing the request to be written immediately following `await` operations. Code produced is similar in style to procedural code. For example:

```
function readCsvFile( csvFile) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject)  => {
        fs.readFile(csvFile, 'UTF-8',
           (err, csv) => err ? reject(err) : resolve( csv)
        );
    });
}
function decodeCsv( csv) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        $.csv.toArrays(csv, {},
           (err, data) => err ? reject( err) : resolve( data)
        );
    });
}

async function addNames( placeName, csvFile) {
    let csv = await readCsvFile( csvFile);
    let arrays = await decodeCsv( csv);
    let names = arrays.map( item => item[0].toString());
    placeName.push.apply( placeName, names);
    return placeName;
}
```

Comment: Please make separate promises for `fs.readFile` and `$.csv.toArrays`. Don't put business logic in non-promise callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the extremely useful feedback. Much appreciated!